# Working alternative for xmlHttpReq and UTF8 characters

Tags: php, ajax, utf-8

Does anyone know a good alternative to xmlHttpReq (post method) that works with all UTF-8 characters?

For example, if you input this `ال` in this demo http://www.degraeve.com/reference/simple-ajax-example.php it will not work. However, if I use formdata `new FormData(document.forms[0])` it works, but this method is not compatible with all browsers.

I'm looking for an all-round solution ? I'm currently using the same method as in the demo (link). It would be even better if I can change something in that script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That script is merely using the wrong method of escaping URL parameters. `window.escape` is not appropriate. Where it uses `escape`, instead just use `encodeURIComponent` and the data will be submitted just fine.

Comment: I tried, but an Arabic letter still become Unicode `%u0648`. I believe this is always like this? Because the variables are passed trough the URL.

Comment: Oh my bad, it seems to be working now! Awesome. In my script there was `+ escape(value ? value : "").replace(/\+/g, "%2B");`. Now `+ encodeURIComponent(value);` works fine! Do you might know what the `.replace...` part should do in the original line?

Comment: I supose it is a regex for replacing, but why

Comment: That changes the encoding of spaces (encoded as `+` by `escape`) to `%2B`, the encoding `encodeURIComponent` uses anyway.

Comment: See http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding.